DragEvent properties coming from nested iFrame
I need to get the clientY of the browser viewport.
However, whenever I drag over an iFrame, event.clientY returns the Yposition of the iFrame viewport.
How can I get only the clientY of the browser viewport?
<div
  onDrag={(e) => console.log(e.clientY)}
  draggable={true}
  style={{
    width: "100px",
    height: "100px",
    background: "black",
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  }}
>
  <iframe
    style={{ width: "50px", height: "50px", background: "white" }}
  />
</div>


For my case, I used a workaround.
Instead of using onDrag, I used onMouseMove like this:
<div
  onMouseMove={(e) => {
    if (e.buttons === 1) console.log(e.clientY);
  }}
  style={{
    width: "100px",
    height: "100px",
    background: "black",
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  }}
>
  <iframe
    style={{ width: "50px", height: "50px", background: "white" }}
  />
</div>

